# How to hover over the word in word cloud

Tags: python

I have created a word cloud from the text file using python by using the module called (pytagcloud),but I have created it as .jpeg file. But i want to make the words in the cloud to be active when I hover the cursor over the words in cloud. 
When I click the particular word in word cloud, the corresponding sentence in the passage should be highlighted.How to do that ? please help me. I have project work in this topic.
I created a gui in which i have options to import the text file and read a text file. after reading text file, I need to produce the word cloud from the passage in .txt file.

```
def wordcloud(self):

        from pytagcloud import create_tag_image, create_html_data, make_tags, LAYOUT_HORIZONTAL, LAYOUTS, LAYOUT_MIX, LAYOUT_VERTICAL, LAYOUT_MOST_HORIZONTAL, LAYOUT_MOST_VERTICAL
        from pytagcloud.lang.counter import get_tag_counts
        from pytagcloud.colors import COLOR_SCHEMES
        import webbrowser

        #import Tkinter
        #from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
        #filename=askopenfilename()

        #with open(filename,'r') as f:
        #    text=f.read()

        #def create_tag_cloud(text):
        words = nltk.word_tokenize(self._contents)
        doc = " ".join(d for d in words[:70])
        tags = make_tags(get_tag_counts(doc), maxsize=100)
        create_tag_image(tags, 'sid.jpeg',size=(1600, 1200),fontname='Philosopher',layout=LAYOUT_MIX,rectangular=True)
        webbrowser.open('sid.jpeg')
```

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Comment: Please show us some code. And anyway, why are you rendering your word cloud as a jpeg ? It can not be interactive that way. What are you working on ? A web application ? A GUI ? What are the technologies you're using ?

Comment: Images aren't interactive. You'll need to export your word cloud into a different format, such as HTML so that you can add events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code there is nothing to correct.

However the best approach to this is to output your tag cloud in `HTML` and `CSS` so you end something like [their demo.](https://www.atizo.com/docs/labs/cloud.html)

After you have your HTML code one approach to take is to use Javascript to react on a word clicked and highlight every occurrence of that word in your body.

However there are many other approaches that may be better suited but without any context it's impossible to comment I'm afraid. Regardless of this don't render your tag cloud as a `jpeg`. This is static and will not have the capability to be interactive.

## Edit1: Code provided

Have a look at the `test_create_html_data(self):` function in the [PyTagCloud tests](https://github.com/atizo/PyTagCloud/blob/master/pytagcloud/test/tests.py) available on github to get an idea of how to output `HTML` and `CSS`.

Just a quick note on your code, Python will be importing all those packages upon every run of your `wordcloud()` method. Pull them out to something like this (I started the adaption for you):

```
from pytagcloud import (create_tag_image, create_html_data, 
    make_tags, LAYOUT_MIX)
from pytagcloud.lang.counter import get_tag_counts
from pytagcloud.colors import COLOR_SCHEMES
import webbrowser

# ...the rest of your code...

def wordcloud(self):
    words = nltk.word_tokenize(self._contents)
    doc = " ".join(d for d in words[:70])

    tags = make_tags(get_tag_counts(doc), maxsize=100)
    data = create_html_data(tags, (1600,1200), layout=LAYOUT_MIX, fontname='Philosopher', rectangular=True)
```

Comment: I provided the code above. How to save it as .html and make it as interactive. please help me., ?